# append from txt-file to dynamically created list, PHP

Tags: php, file-handling, createelement

New to PHP and have been struggeling for a while with how to create a list-element i PHP but cant seem to understand how it works, thougt it was alot like javascript... I have a txt-file that I'm appending information from a form to and want to append the first two ; sepparated text-blocks to a dynamically created list element when the form submits? how do I create a list-element and how do I add the information from the txt-file to it?

for now i have this code in php, and it works with echoing info from the txt-file but I cant create a list-element and append the text, any tips would be appreciated?

```
<?php                       
                    if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
                        if( $_POST['filmnamn'] != "" &&    $_POST['betyg'] != "" &&    $_POST['link'] != "" &&    $_POST['photo'] != "" &&    $_POST['description'] != "") {
                            $myFile = 'demo.txt';
                            $titel = $_POST['filmnamn'] . ";" ;
                            $betyg = $_POST['betyg'] . ";" ;
                            $link = $_POST['link'] . ";" ;
                            $photo = $_POST['photo'] . ";" ;
                            $desc = $_POST['description'].PHP_EOL;
                            $data = "$titel$betyg$link$photo$desc";
                            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
                            fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
                            fwrite($fh, $data);
                            fclose($fh);

                            $filename = ('demo.txt');
                            $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
                            $fileinfo = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                            $fileinfo_array = explode(';', $fileinfo);
                            echo $fileinfo_array[0].$fileinfo_array[1];

                            $div = getElementById('filmlista');
                            $list = createElement("li", $fileinfo_array[0]);
                            $list->setAttribute("class","listan");
                            $div->appendChild($list);

                        }
                    }
?>
```

Comment: php's interaction with html elements is nothing like javascript.  Think of it more as writing to a text file.

Comment: so I need to open the index.php like i do with the textfile and then navigate through it and find the div where I want to insert my list?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you're trying to use php to alter existing html which is possible but not the regular use.

Normally php gets information about layout in templates and information from database and puts together this in any way you want.

Try smarty and read about mvc design.
http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

Or take the red pill and code as you like.

Godnatt! ;-)

Comment: jo jag vet att det php fungerar så men jag måste ju lära mig hur man kan manipulera det på olika sätt, tror jag tar det röda pillret och somnar snart också, sov gott :)